# HTML page editing

Tags: html, browser

In an attempt to learn HTML, I thought it may be a good idea to edit some simple code. So, I navigated to what I figured was a simple layout on a website and copied the source to my desktop. I made minor changes and attempted then to reopen the HTML file in a browser to see the changes.

Instead of the same layout with a few minor adjustments, the entire scheme was deformed. The wording was all there(no longer formatted), but the background was now white and all the links appeared structrually in one column on the left side of the screen.

So, in essense, what is the best way to learn HTML and why didn't my attempt at editing work? Are there more files required than provded by a simple source save provides?

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Start with [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

Comment: Most likely there were linked styles that were not downloaded using this approach, that's why the page was deformed (no style definitions). You don't need to use another source to learn HTML, you should just start with an empty file and some online tutorials.

Comment: There are a lot of resources out there. Google is very much your friend. I'd start by looking for HTML tutorials, then CSS tutorials.

Comment: You copied the HTML source, but you didn't copy the style sheets, JavaScript, images, anything that could be in a separate file.  Look through the HTML source for any files that it references, you'll need those as well.

Comment: The site you attempted to edit may have had an external stylesheet referenced, the link probably broke when you copied the page to your computer

Answer (score 2):

The HTML likely references things by **RELATIVE PATH**, e.g. a CSS File included with `/styles/...` not `http://originaldomain.com/styles/...`  So if you just saved the HTML, none of the relative paths will resolve.  Most browsers allow you to file --> save page as, which will copy not just the file but also the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Try www.w3schools.com/html/ should give you a good start and a good understanding. Don't try and run before you can walk! And try learning CSS aswell

Comment: Please don't keep spreading w3schools as a good resource, see http://www.w3fools.com/. There are lots of other resources out there with more updated and better informatoin, http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/tutorials for example.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren: Damn you beat me to it by like 5 seconds... but you get a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The file you needed was an external CSS file. It is linked to in the head of the document. This site is better than w3schools, www.w3fools.com
There are a lot of videos out there. Try  www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming 
That community is much laid back and friendly!